# BLE scanning filtering not working with Samsung Note 10

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

I just discovered that scanning with serviceUid set into the ScanFilter will prevent scanResults from being returned to the callback. This works on Pixel and other devices and seems to only affect Samsung Note 10 (Plus).

This won't work.

```
internal class Scanner {

    private val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid("someUuid"))
            .setManufacturerData(someIntId, someByteArray, someMask)
            .build()

    private fun startScan(scanSettings: ScanSettings, scanCallback: ScanCallback) 
    {
        bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(scanFilter), scanSettings, scanCallback)
    }
```

This will work.

```
internal class Scanner {

    private val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            //.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid("someUuid"))
            .setManufacturerData(someIntId, someByteArray, someMask)
            .build()

    private fun startScan(scanSettings: ScanSettings, scanCallback: ScanCallback) 
    {
        bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(scanFilter), scanSettings, scanCallback)
    }
```

Comment: What Android versions are you using? And what peripheral devices are you using? Starting with Android 8, the BLE scanner discards all advertisement message that contain invalid information. And many devices indeed advertise invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. Please refer my below code, I am not sure about this because I do not tested, hope it works!

```
        val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid("someUuid")).build()
        val scanFilter1 = ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(someIntId, someByteArray, someMask).build()
        val arrayList = ArrayList<ScanFilter>()
        arrayList.add(scanFilter)
        arrayList.add(scanFilter1)

        private fun startScan(scanSettings: ScanSettings, scanCallback: ScanCallback)
        {
            bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(arrayList, scanSettings, scanCallback)
        }
```